# SQL Count distinct with group by issue

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I have this code:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE LIB.ONETOONE AS
        SELECT GCI_MRA, MRATempName, COUNT(DISTINCT CUSTOMERID) AS COUNT
        FROM LIB.MRA_FINAL
        GROUP BY GCI_MRA, MRATempName;
QUIT;
```

This works for one of my tables, but when im trying the exact same code on another table, it is outputting column customerID in the result, even though i only specified group by on GCI_MRA and MRATempName, any idea why this is the case?

Thanks!

Example of the output looks like this (sorry for not including earlier):

```
GCI_MRA     MRATempName     CustomerID  Count
Null        Null            111         5
Null        Null            222         3
Null        Null            333         8
123         ABCD            888         2
```

CustomerID shouldn't be in the results, and count should really be 3, which is the three distinct occurences of customerID within the grouping of GCI_MRA (null) + MRATempName (null). But right now it appears to be a count of the number of each value of customerID.

Ideally the code would (and it did for my other table) output something like this:

```
GCI_MRA      MRATempName      count
Null         Null             3
123          ABCD             1
```

Comment: Could you tell us how did you try on on another table, and what's your DBMS..?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please give sample data and the results you are getting. This sounds unlikely in any RDBMS though.

Comment: If it were grouping on all 3 columns, the result would be that all the counts would be `1`. Is that really what you're seeing?

Comment: @Barmar no i am seeing the number of distinct C values, so for example one row would be NULL A NULL B and 10 count of value '111' for C, and the next row would also be NULL A NULL B but 8 count of value '222' for C

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I am using PROC SQL within SAS.

Comment: Where are you seeing the value of C? It's never being selected.

Comment: @Barmar that is exactly what baffles me lol. I never selected C, only to count(distinct C) and output it as a count number. For some reason it's showing up in my output as an actual column, and the count is also on the number of a particular value of C, rather than the number of distinct Cs within the grouping.

Comment: I don't use SAS, but I'm finding this difficult to believe. SQL processors don't add columns on their own, it would be an incredibly serious bug. This is the result you'd expect from `SELECT a, b, c, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY a, b, c`. Check your code again to make sure you're not doing this.

Comment: @Barmar I completely agree to what you are saying, I've checked the code again and again. That's why I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: I doubt the column names are really A, B, and C, so you're not pasting the query verbatim, and something is being lost in translation to fake column names. Please copy and paste the actual query.

Comment: Post your actual code used and log that generated this issue. Most likely it's not working and you're seeing old results or something like that.

Comment: If the `LIB`  libref is a libname connecting to a remote data base library it is highly possible the table to be created by the query already exists.  RDBMS systems do not replace existing tables -- typically you will drop a table before recreating it again with a second run of a `create table` query.

Comment: I suggest you **don't** use `COUNT` as a column alias, instead call it something that isn't a SQL word.